# RegKey Value in to a variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the below code snippet:

```
$Reg2 = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $Machine)
 $RegKey2= $Reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\TrendMicro\\PC-cillinNTCorp\\CurrentVersion\\Misc.")
 $CheckAVVer = $RegKey2.GetValue("ProgramVer")
```

Whats happening is $CheckAVVer doesn't seem to grab the value. If remove the $CheckAVVer, it works and displays the value.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second line, change:

```
$Reg.OpenSubKey("SOFT...
```

To:

```
$Reg2.OpenSubKey("SOFT...
```

And see if that fixes it for you.

```
$Reg2 = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $Machine)
$RegKey2= $Reg2.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\TrendMicro\\PC-cillinNTCorp\\CurrentVersion\\Misc.")
$CheckAVVer = $RegKey2.GetValue("ProgramVer")
Write-host $CheckAVVer
```